# How to dump data to DVD when the disk space reach 80% on RAID 1, and clean the dumped space from disk after burn

Tags: linux, php, centos, freebsd, perl

How to monitor in unix (FreeBSD) /linux (CentOS 5.6) the disk space if its greater or equal to 80%?

If its equal or greater then 80%. How can i tell dump the data from a specific /misc/ folder to DVD and empty the space that was burned to DVD. So that it never cross 80% threshold?

```
example: * * * * * /usr/bin/php or perl /myscript
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your comfort level with scripting.  The standard command for most flavors of Unix to check disk space is "df"  The output of this could easily be integrated with a simple script that does something when df discovers a value above 80.  Google will locate lots of similar things, you just have to pick a language or a shell.